# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list' python

Tags: python, csv

I am printing some corrupt data in the terminal by using print statement in python. first when I read data from csv file and print it in the terminal, it looks like

```
[' 122    32   5   0.112'] 
[' 122    42   5   0.153']
[' 122    23   5   0.153']
[' 122    24   2   0.156']
```

there are above 1000 rows and I want them to count but when i used count command , it gives me error. my code is

```
with open('file-name', 'rb') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines
    count = 0    
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k >= (int(start-header-lines)):
            data = line.split()
            if len(data) != 3:
                print 'faulty-data', data
                count += data
                continue
```

after printing faulty-lines i got this data

```
[ '122' , '32' ,  '5' ,  '0.112'] 
[ '122' , '42' ,  '5' ,  '0.153']
[ '122' , '23' ,  '5' ,  '0.153']
[ '122' , '24' ,  '2' ,  '0.156']
```

I want to count these faulty rows and I try count but i get this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Can someone tell me how to count those faulty lines with count, because i know how many rows are corrupt and I am printing them , but I want to count them also. I am new , so maybe my question seems silly. 
thanx.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. `data_tmp` is not defined. My guess is that the error is arroung `count += data_tmp` (which I could be sure of provided you had given the full traceback), but I cannot be certain.

Comment: @Rightleg sorry typing error. it was data and not data_tmp.

Comment: @Rightleg I search over SO , but those solutions were different and couldn't meet my case.

Comment: How in the world are you getting `[ '122'    '32'   '5'   '0.112'] `? Python wouldn't print it out that way, it would be `['122', '32', '5', '0.122']`. *copy* and *paste* your output (also the *full* text of the traceback). Please learn how to produce a [mcve]

Comment: @WayneWerner you are right. I edit my code and sorry for so many mistakes. I will be very careful in future. thanx a lot for marking my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split` method returns a list. Therefore, the following declares `data` as a list:

```
data = line.split()
```

On the other hand, `count` is defined as an integer:

```
count = 0
```

However, you are trying to add `data` to `count`:

```
count += data
```

It makes no logical sense to add a list to an integer, and that is basically what the error you get tells you.

It seems that you want to count the lines. Therefore, just increment `count`. Your code becomes:

```
with open('file-name', 'rb') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines
    count = 0    
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k >= (int(start-header-lines)):
            data = line.split()
            if len(data) != 3:
                print 'faulty-data', data
                count += 1    # Increment count for each faulty line
                continue
```

---

Answering here to your comment: you are asking how you can count the total number of faulty lines over several files.

The solution is pretty easy: put the former code in a function that takes a file in parameter.

```
def count_faulty_lines(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:    # The first parameter of open is the path
            lines = f.readlines()
            print lines
        count = 0    
        for k, line in enumerate(lines):
            if k >= (int(start-header-lines)):
                data = line.split()
                if len(data) != 3:
                    print 'faulty-data', data
                    count += 1
                    continue
    return count
```

Then sum the result of this function for the targeted files:

```
paths = ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', ...)
sum(count_faulty_lines(path) for path in paths)
```

Comment: thanx for the help. yes I want to count lines only. I will apply this solution and will come back soon.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it works, but I have one little question. I had 3 files and it counts faulty lines for each file and then it start again. How can I get total faulty lines of all files combine together. .thanx forr the help.

Comment: thanks a lot for the guidance. the solutions works fine now.